# particle.js background in flex container

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, particles.js

EDIT: Ive reworded my question a bit in hopes of getting more of a response. Basically all I need at this count is a flex container that holds the items just as mine does, with particlesJS in the background.Even if someone can just make a flex container with the particles as the background, I could probably figure it out from there.

PEN https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/zdjGJZ

```
<div id="particles-js">
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<div class="svg-container">
  <div class="svg-logo">
    <svg width="115px" height="60px">
    <rect x="3" y="3" rx="3px" ry="4px" width="52.2px" height="52.2px"
style="fill: aqua;stroke:aqua;stroke-width:1px;opacity:0.82" />
    <text x="21.5" y="33.6" font-family="sf-san-francisco" font-
size="20" stroke="black" fill="black">T</text>
    <rect x="61.2" y="3" rx="4px" ry="4px" width="52px" height="52px"
style="fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-width:2.4px;opacity:0.82" />
    <text x="79" y="33.6" font-family="sf-san-francisco" font-size="20" 
fill="white">R</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question-container">
  <p class="questions" id="border-bottom">WHO AM I?</p>
  <p class="questions" id="border-top">WHAT DO I DO?</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="middle">
<div class="top">
  <nav>
    <a>Link1</a>
    <a>Link2</a>
    <a>Link3</a>
    <a>Link4</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <h1>I am an extremely</br> passionate User Interface</br> Design + 
Developer</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="right">
<h2 class="name">TRAVIS MARTIN</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js">
</script>

.container{
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
}

#particles-js{
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
background-image: 
url('https://www.hdwallpapers.net/wallpapers/molecular-
structure-wallpaper-for-1280x800-69-739.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}



.left{
display: flex;
flex: 1;
background: rgba(9, 0, 31, 0.82);
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
padding-top: 40px;
}
.svg-container{
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 80px;
}

/*.svg-logo{
display: flex;
flex-grow: .25;

background: teal;
}*/



.question-container{
display: flex;
flex-grow: 1;
width: 100%;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: flex-end;
margin-top: 40px;
}

.questions{
display: flex;
margin:0 1px 0 0;
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
}
#border-top{
border-top: 2px solid white;
padding: 15px; 

}
#border-bottom{
padding: 13px;
padding-right: 28px;
}


.middle{
display: flex;
flex: 3;

flex-direction: column;
}
.top{
display: flex;
flex: 1;
}
nav{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
margin: 50px 0 0 65px;
color: white;

}

a:before {
content: '\2014';
position: absolute;
margin-left: -40px;
}
a{
margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
font-size: 22px;
}


.bottom{
display: flex;
flex: 1;  
}
h1{
margin-left: 25px;
font-size: 55px;
color: white;
}


.right{
display: flex;
flex: .37;
background: rgba(6, 2, 28, 0.94);
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
min-width: 0;
}

.name{
display: flex;
transform: rotate(-180deg);
background: pink;
writing-mode: tb-lr;   
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
font-size: 65px;
align-items: center;

color: white;
}

var options = {"particles":{"number":{"value":99,"density":
{"enable":true,"value_area":552.4033491425909}},"color":
{"value":"#ffffff"},"shape":{"type":"circle","stroke":
{"width":0,"color":"#000000"},"polygon":{"nb_sides":3},"image":
{"src":"img/github.svg","width":70,"height":100}},"opacity":
{"value":1,"random":true,"anim":
{"enable":false,"speed":1,"opacity_min":0.1,"sync":false}},"size":
{"value":2,"random":true,"anim":
{"enable":false,"speed":40,"size_min":0.1,"sync":false}},"line_linked"
{"enable":false,"distance":150,"color":"#ffffff","opacity":0.4,
"width":1},"move":

{"enable":true,"speed":1.5782952832645452,"direction":"none",

"random":true,"straight":false,"out_mode":"out","bounce":false,
"attract":{"enable":false,"rotateX":600,"rotateY":1200}}},
"interactivity":{"detect_on":"canvas","events":{"onhover":
{"enable":false,"mode":"repulse"},"onclick":
{"enable":true,"mode":"repulse"},"resize":true},"modes":{"grab":
{"distance":400,"line_linked":{"opacity":1}},"bubble":
{"distance":400,"size":40,"duration":2,"opacity":8,"speed":3},
 "repulse":{"distance":200,"duration":0.4},"push":
 {"particles_nb":4},"remove":
 {"particles_nb":2}}},"retina_detect":false};

 particlesJS("particles-js", options);
```

Comment: ok whats happening in my brackets (where there are no issues with particles.js dependency), is the particles are showing up in their own new section below the background image. For some reason they are not covering the bg image. Is it the flex properties causing the issue here?

Comment: Bascially all I need is to know whether I can use partcle.js as a background in a flexbox layout. I can't find anything on google about it, any work around that Im not aware of?

Comment: Don't make the `container` a child of `particles-js`, make them siblings ... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvGYvO

Comment: I gave that a shot and It does put the particles over the background as I wished. However, It pushes all of the containers and Items held inside the "container" div to the bottom of the screen. Now not covering the background. This obviously isn't going to work. I now just need those flex items back were they were (over top of the background).

Comment: If you checked the codepen I made in previous comment, you'll see I gave `particles-js` absolute position and the `container` a relative position (so it won't be hidden by the `particles-js`)